# Nginx and uWSGI Flask app Connection Refused

Tags: nginx, deployment, uwsgi, wsgi, flask

Trying to set up a Flask application with uWSGI and Nginx.

I keep getting a 502 Bad Gateway error (as far as I know this means uWSGI and Nginx can't communicate correctly)

This is the line that keeps showing up in my /var/log/nginx/error.log:

```
2016/07/29 17:07:12 [error] 24958#24958: *2 connect() to unix:/home/lit/howlit/how_lit_restapi.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
```

This is my project directory and it's permissions:

```
(env) root@digitalocean:/home/lit/howlit# ls -l 
total 24
drwx---r-x 6 lit www-data 4096 Jul 29 11:47 env
-rwx---r-x 1 lit www-data  141 Jul 29 17:00 howlit.ini
-rwx---r-x 1 lit www-data 1175 Jul 29 11:52 how_lit_restapi.py
-rwx---r-x 1 lit www-data 1781 Jul 29 11:54 how_lit_restapi.pyc
srwx---r-x 1 lit www-data    0 Jul 29 16:46 how_lit_restapi.sock
-rwx---r-x 1 lit www-data   73 Jul 29 11:54 wsgi.py
-rwx---r-x 1 lit www-data  218 Jul 29 11:54 wsgi.pyc
```

This is my howlit.ini file:

```
(env) root@digitalocean:/home/lit/howlit# cat howlit.ini
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app


master = true
processes = 5


socket = how_lit_restapi.sock

chmod-sock = 660

vaccum = true

die-on-term = true
```

this is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/how_lit file:

```
(env) root@digitalocean:/home/lit/howlit# cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/how_lit 
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name XXX.XX.XX.XXX;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/lit/howlit/how_lit_restapi.sock;
    }

}
```

*the xxxs are to protect my server IP; there is a real IP address there.

Here is the nginx conf file:

```
user lit;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Permissions of directory with socket:

root@digitalocean:~# ls -l /home/lit/howlit/

```
total 24
drwx---r-x 6 lit www-data 4096 Jul 29 11:47 env
-rwx---r-x 1 lit www-data  141 Jul 29 19:01 howlit.ini
-rwx---r-x 1 lit www-data 1175 Jul 29 11:52 how_lit_restapi.py
-rwx---r-x 1 lit www-data 1781 Jul 29 11:54 how_lit_restapi.pyc
srwx---r-x 1 lit www-data    0 Jul 29 16:46 how_lit_restapi.sock
-rwx---r-x 1 lit www-data   73 Jul 29 11:54 wsgi.py
-rwx---r-x 1 lit www-data  218 Jul 29 11:54 wsgi.pyc
```

I've tried changing permissions and the files alot. What is my problem here? Why is the connection being refused???

UPDATE:

So when I run my application manually:

```
root@digitalocean:/home/lit/howlit# python how_lit_restapi.py
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

and I go to my ip address at:

```
XXX.XX.XX:5000
```

my app shows up, so I know uwwsgi is running and serving. But the nginx hand off is not work.

Here is my how_lit.service file as well.

```
root@digitalocean:/home/lit/howlit# vim /etc/systemd/system/how_lit.service 

[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve how lit rest api
After=network.target


[Service]
User=lit
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/lit/howlit/
Environment="PATH=/home/lit/howlit/env/bin"
ExecStart=/home/lit/howlit/env/bin/uwsgi --ini howlit/howlit.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Okay then now I think I have it. The how_lit service is failing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd move towards specifying an 'upstream' where you set your server/socket and reference that in your virtual host, like:

```
upstream django {
  server unix:///var/run/whatever.sock; # for a file socket
}

server {
   listen   80
   location / {
       uwsgi_pass django;
   }
}
```

You can use lsof to make sure things are writing to / reading from the socket.

Comment: How does this help with the question asked?

Comment: could you please explain an upstream? and why this would solve my problem? I thought the ini file takes care of that

Comment: Upstream is for defining an upstream handler for a virtual host.  The ini file takes care of things from the uwsgi side, but uwsgi is upstream from nginx. It's a different approach to the config, but it's what has worked for me in many situations.

Answer (score 0):

Which user is running `uwsgi`? In your config file, you've specified:

```
chmod-sock = 660
```

This means, the user in question and his group are able to read / write, all other users aren't able to do anything. Try changing it to

```
chmod-sock = 666
```

and see how this goes.

A better alternative might be to put the `uwsgi` user and the one running `nginx` into the same group.

**Edit:** Does the `socket` exist at the path you've specified? If not, change the `socket` directive so that it uses a full / absolute path.

Comment: i actually dont know whose running uwsgi might be root. but i changed chmod-sock = 666 and nothing happened

Comment: and yes in that directory there is a .sock file, so there is a socket

Comment: @KyleCalica-St Did you restart `uwsgi` afterwards? If so, could you please show the permissions of the socket?

Comment: I added it the directory listing with the socket at the end.

Comment: The permissions obviously doesn't correspond to the `chmod-sock` directive in your config. Could you put the socket (just for debugging) into `/tmp/`? Of course, alter your `nginx` config appropriately.

Comment: kinda new to the socket stuff. By my understanding you want me to create a .sock file (the socket) and open it in /tmp/? Why would that be easier for debugging?

Comment: i also discovered i can see my app if i run the application myself but only at port 5000.

Comment: sent the socket to  /tmp and still getting the issue digging through logs rn.

Comment: sending the socket to /tmp worked so i know now its an issue of it being created but not accessible.

Comment: @KyleCalica-St Make sure that the permissions are sane, and the socket is read- and writeable by the user running nginx.

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the troubleshooting steps you might need to perform -

1). Check the uwsgi logs, usually under /var/log/uwsig - look for errors and make sure the app you specified in your configuration as `module = wsgi:app` is loading.

2). Check for any permission issues. To make this easier, start uwsgi under the same user/group as nginx. You can add the line below to your uwsgi config -

```
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
```

3). You might need to install `uwsgi-plugin-python` package and add `plugins = python` to your uwsgi config. I had cases where the app was not loading due to missing plugin.

Comment: hmm i dont have a var/log/uwsgi is that because i only installed it through pip?

Comment: Possibly, you can still specify the log file for uwsgi using `logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log` for instance. Make sure the user under which uwsgi is running has read/write access to the log directory/file.

Comment: its actually my service that i made to execute uwsgi that is failing. the service is never up.

Comment: what do the logs say? Add `--logto2 /tmp/mylog.log` to your `ExecStart` line and restart the service and report what you see in the /tmp/mylog.log file.